# Why is my transistor switched output so low?

Tags: voltage

Help needed! I am using an Arduino Nano and a general purpose npn (2n2222a) transistor to provide a 12v signal to a low current 12vdc load in an automobile. The Arudino code is set to pulse D2 at bootup/startup for .5 second. The PWM output setting was 255 (since switched to digitalWrite). However, the switched output measures only 4.5v (expected close to 12v). What am i doing wrong?
Applying 12v+ directly to the black box works. The purpose is to simulate a temporary button push in the car so an auto function is enabled.

[image]

Comment: the black box is raising the voltage on the emitter ... that in turn raises the base voltage necessary for transistor to turn on ... the nano is not able to supply that voltage .... connect the emitter to GND ... place black box at the collector .... this has been beat to death here and many places ... do research about driving a motor or solenoid or lamp with an arduinp

Comment: I did do research, and found this circuit (4th circuit, emitter-follower) which looked close to my desired application: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html#:~:text=PNP%20Relay%20Switch%20Circuit.%20The%20PNP%20transistor%20circuit,is%20more%20negative%20than%20that%20at%20the%20Emitter.

Comment: the problem with your circuit is that D2 does not rise to 12 V

Comment: How much current is needed for your black box with 12 V supply?

Comment: not much current - it's supplying a signal to an auto control unit simulating a short button press - a few milliamps at a guess.

Comment: Your schematic shows a **common collector** amplifier: it amplifies current, not voltage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an NPN transistor as a high side switch.

The voltage at the emitter of the transistor will always be about 0.7V below the voltage at the base.  The "high" output from the Arduino is 5V.  The emitter will be at about 4.3V.

Have a look at the Wikipedia ["emitter follower"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector) page.  The emitter follower is also called a common collector circuit. That explains the "problem" in more detail.  It is only a problem in so far as it is not the correct solution for your task.

You need to use a ["common emitter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter) circuit.

This usage is commonly called a "low side switch."

That would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFoH9v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your black box really needs its input pulled up to 12V, then you would do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDcNCM.png)</sup>

The resistor values and transistor part numbers are place holders.  The values of resistors you will need depends on the transistors you use.  The transistor selection will depend on how much current you need to deliver to the black box.

I see in a comment that your black box only needs a few milliamperes.  In that case, the shown transistors should work just fine.  The resistor values may be a little too high, but I think they'll be OK.

---

A couple of additional points:

1. The Arduino has PWM outputs, not PCM.
2. The output voltage for your black box will be pulsing if you use any PWM value lower than 255.  Your black box probably won't like that, and your voltmeter won't read a correct voltage.

You should use D2 as a digital output rather than PWM.  Just turn it on or off rather than fiddling with the PWM duty cycle.  Use ["digitalWrite"](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/) instead of ["analogWrite"](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) on pin D2.

Comment: Thanks, i switched to digitalWrite in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The 2N2222 is an [*NPN*](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html) device. Skipping all of the physics involved, that means that (in your application) it will ***sink*** current as a *low-side switch*, but not ***source*** current as a *high-side switch*.

If you want a *high-side switch*, you should find a *PNP* transistor. In this case your Nano pin will **sink** current from the transistor's base terminal.

I would recommend you stick with the 2N2222, but make two changes:

1. Connect your "black box" between the positive terminal (+) of your 12V supply, and the **collector** terminal of the 2N2222.
2. Reduce the size of your base resistor from 10Kohms to 1Kohms

Comment: The ground side of the black box is not available. The black box (control unit) circuit has to supply +12v to simulate the switch press.

Comment: thanks, I only had npn transistors on hand, so that's what I tried.

Comment: checked the parts bin, I also have a p-ch mosfet and nte184/185's.

Comment: @Seamus: An NPN transistor will quite happily source current as a high side switch.  Tha'ts what it does - it is an emitter follower.  What it can't do is to provide a voltage at the emitter that is higher than the base voltage.

Comment: No, Seamus, I'm not looking for a "chat room."  I spend most of my time on the electrical engineering stack exchange.  The statement "but not source current as a high-side switch" is incorrect.  As the original question shows it, the 2N2222 would try to deliver all the current available from the 12V source to the black box.  If the black box were a short circuit to ground, the 2N2222 would quickly burn out from trying to pass many amperes of current from the car battery.  So much for "not sourcing current."

Comment: As used, the black box won't consume much current (there's a comment that says it only needs a few milliamperes.)  That doesn't change the fact that an NPN transistor used as a high side switch can quite happily source current from its emitter.

Comment: Already posted an answer.

Comment: And an NPN transistor **will** deliver current as shown in the question.  Or haven't you tried it?

Comment: I did try my original circuit in car, but it would not provide enough voltage? to signal the control unit to switch states. A straight +12vdc line to the control unit does switch the state.

Comment: @handyguy: Right - the circuit you drew in your question won't work. The collector needs to go to the `neg/gnd/-` terminal of your black box, and the emitter needs to go to the GND point on your Arduino. Does this mean it's working for you now?

Comment: I do not have access to the ground on the black box. I only have access to the signal wire to the control unit, which required a +12vdc signal.

Comment: @handyguy: OK - that's easy enough to fix. I'll be glad to revise my answer if you'll consider it - let me know if you don't mind.

Comment: i don't mind, thanks

Comment: @handyguy: I wasn't clear; my apologies, but I wanted to know if you were still **interested** in a revised answer. If you've moved on with a solution already, there may be no point in revising this answer. OTOH, if you're still undecided as to how to proceed, I'll be glad to make the changes.

Comment: thanks, but no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

What I have thought about is using an opto-coupler
[image]

Connect the Arduino pin output to pin 1 through 330 ohms resistor, pin 2 to ground of Arduino, connect pin 4 to Vcc of 12 V and finally connect pin 3 to the black box load.

Try this configuration

Since black box only needs few milliamps as you said
May be the transistor is not ***saturated*** since base current has to go through the black box load opto-coupler s have ***no base current instead they use photons***

Here is the circuit diagram

[image]

5 V supply looks like the Arduino pin D2 and lamp is the black box load.
This is 4N35 example

Comment: The opto coupler looks like a good idea. The part is cheap and small. If it can switch 12vdc at a few ma, it looks like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]ok, so i chose the 2 transistor high side circuit as i had the needed pnp transistor laying around. Works great, thanks everyone for your help. The trace (5v/div) shows the Arduino signal at 5v and the circuit output at 12v - perfect!
[image]
[image]